# Exchanging Data between 2 XAP files that are in separate browser windows

Tags: silverlight

What's the best way to exchange Data between 2 XAP files that are in separate browser windows or maybe a browser window and a popup? each html/window with it's own .xap file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take look at the `LocalMessageReceiver` and `LocalMessageSender` classes in the [System.Windows.Messaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messaging(v=VS.95).aspx) namespace.  For an overview for how this works review [Communication Between Local Silverlight-Based Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833063(v=VS.95).aspx).